# mocking attribute of class that is used in tested class

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to write unit tests for my django app but failing to correctly use mock.patch.

my code :

apps\MyApp\DataAccessLayer\CctDAO.py :

```
from ..models import CCT
from ..serializers import CctSerializer


"""
    get a list of all CCTs

    @return a list of all the CCTs
"""
def getAll() -> list[dict]:
    entities = CCT.objects.all()
    serializer = CctSerializer(entities, many=True)

    return serializer.data
```

apps\Myapp\serializers.py :

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine.serializers import DocumentSerializer

from .models import CCT

"""
    serializer to encode and decod CCT to JSON
"""
class CctSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CCT
        exclude = ('id', ) #using custom id field instead of the default
```

my test case :

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock

from .DataAccessLayer import CctDAO

class Test_CCT_DAO(TestCase) :

    # @mock.patch('apps.MyApp.DataAccessLayer.CctDAO.CCT.objects.all', return_value=['mocked-data1'])

    @mock.patch.object(CctDAO.CctSerializer, 'data', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock, return_value = ['mocked-data1'])
    def test_getall_empty(self, mock1=None, mock2=None):
        print(CctDAO.getAll())
        self.assertEqual(['mocked-data2'], CctDAO.getAll())
```

In this test case `CctDAO.getAll()` returns `[]`, abd not my mocked data.

I also tried:

```
 @mock.patch.object(CctDAO, 'CctSerializer.data', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock, return_value = ['mocked-data1'])
```

But this results in an error that the CctDAO module does not have the attribute 'CctSerializer.data'.

I also tried:

```
@mock.patch('apps.MyApp.DataAccessLayer.CctDAO.CctSerializer.data', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock, return_value=['mocked-data1'])
```

Which returns `[]` as well, and not the mocked data.

How am I suppose to patch `CCT.objects.all()` and `serializer.data` correctly?